# Firebase encrypt a push key to de-identify the relationship of 2 collections

Tags: node.js, encryption, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to de-identify my users from their other "records". What I have done so far is put the `personal identifiable information` in one collection and `encrypt` it's push key or `uid` using a `secret-key` (using crypto) to remove the pointer to the user's "records".

However, what I want to make sure that only the user could access his data. How do I do that with crypto?

**User**

```
users:{
    key1:{
       // personal identifiable info
    }
}
```

Encrypt `key1` using a secret = `some_hash`

**Other records**

```
foo:{
    some_hash:{
        // other data
    }
}
```

If the user wants his data the server (nodejs) will again encrypt his `key1` using the secret to create `some_hash` and use it to get the path to his data.

Is this secure enough? Thanks.

Comment: You should use Firebase Database Security Rules to tell the user it can only read it's own data.

Comment: @Lirianer no I want to de-identify the data not just restrict it to other user.